# change specific value of an array with dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a browse page I want to change value of islLiked from true to false or the opposite depends onClick that give me the id of the user

```
//this is how i set the result into state
{ ...state, browser: { ...state.browser, result: payload } };
```

this is my state [image]

this is my reducer

```
export const profileInitState = {
  photo: {
    loading: true,
    profile_Image: "",
    cover_Image: "",
    first_Image: "",
    second_Image: "",
    third_Image: "",
    fourth_Image: ""
  },
  info: {
    loading: true,
    liked: false,
    matched: false,
    blocked: false,
    id: "",
    user_first_name: "",
    user_last_name: "",
    user_gender: "",
    user_relationship: "",
    user_birth_day: "",
    user_birth_month: "",
    user_gender_interest: "",
    user_birth_year: "",
    user_age: "",
    user_tags: "",
    user_city: "",
    user_current_occupancy: "",
    user_biography: "",
    user_set_from_map: null,
    user_fame_rate: 0,
    user_location: {
      lat: "",
      lng: ""
    }
  },
  browser: {
    result: [],
    sort_by: ""
  }
};

export const profileReducer = (state, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case PHOTO_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, photo: payload };
    case INFO_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, info: payload };
    case PROFILE_BLOCKED:
      return { ...state, info: { ...state.info, blocked: payload } };
    case PROFILE_LIKED:
      return { ...state, info: { ...state.info, liked: payload } };
    case PROFILE_MATCHED:
      return { ...state, info: { ...state.info, matched: payload } };
    case BROWSER_RETURN:
      return { ...state, browser: { ...state.browser, result: payload } };
    case SET_NEW_ISLIK:
    // i want to keep the previouse result and change only the value of islike with the value of payload but just for the chossen user with the same id it will also be on payload: {
        //isLike: res.fromdb,
        //valide: id
      //}
    case SORT_BY_BACK:
      return { ...state, browser: { ...state.browser, sort_by: payload } };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

the new value of isLike will be on the payload

I'm wondering if there is a way to do that with the help of id of the user hope you get what I try to explain

Comment: You use Redux ?

Comment: @EmmanuelMericdeBellefon I'm using context api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do it :

```
case SET_NEW_ISLIK:
  return {
    ...state,
    browser: {
      ...state.browser,
      result: state.browser.result.map(user => (
        user.id === payload.userId
        ? { ...user, isLiked: payload.isLiked }
        : user )
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: This loses the order, the newly edited user is always put in the bottom. I would suggest you use reduce or map.

Comment: ...prevState.browser.result.map(user => (user.id === userId ? { ...user, isLiked: !user.isLiked } : user  ))

Comment: to add to my comment, this way you don't have to iterate through browser.result twice, you're doing one to get the user and then again to filter

Comment: You don't need this: const user = prevState.browser.result.find(user => user.id === userId) anymore ;)

Comment: can you please see the update on the question thank you for ur help

Comment: did you change ```payload.userId``` and ```payload.isLiked``` to proper variables ? I don't know the shape of your payload.

Comment: the console log of payload is `{isLiked: false, userId: 5}
isLiked: false
userId: 5`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204086/discussion-between-buk-lau-and-emmanuel-meric-de-bellefon).